# php - fwrite edit from line X to line X

Tags: php, file, line, fwrite

I created a calendar with its data stored in a text file. For the moment, I can only edit one line/day at the same time, but I would like to edit many days (same content from sept 15th to sept 19th for example). How to do this ?

My text file with the data looks like this (with $id going from 1 to 31) and $exp is the content I edit.

```
        $id|$exp|$color|$color2
```

And the php file allowing the editing looks like this:

```
        $month_file = $file . ".txt"; 
        $month_db = file("$month_file");
        $call = fopen("$month_file","w");

        foreach($month_db as $month_line) {
            $month_line_arr = explode("|",$month_line);
            $month_line_id = $month_line_arr[0];
        if($month_line_id == $id) {
        fwrite($call,"$month_line_arr[0]|$exp|$color|$color2\n");
        }else {
        fwrite($call,"$month_line");
        }
        }


        fclose($call);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if($month_line_id == $id) {
```

to:

```
if ($month_line_id >= $min_id && $month_line_id <= $max_id) {
```

where `$min_id` and `$max_id` contain 15 and 19 in your example.

BTW, you can use `fgetcsv()` to read the line and split it into columns in one step, and then `fputcsv()` to write it back that way.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine now !! 
I didn't know about the fgetcsv() function, I will take a look at it =)